# Kendo UI Multi select selected values from datasource

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-multiselect

I want to add a datasource to the multiselect so it can display the selected options. I want the following:

```
            $("#shareReadMultiSelect").kendoMultiSelect(
            {
                autoBind: true,
                dataSource: schedulerUsersSource,
                dataTextField: "text",
                dataValueField: "value",
                value: selectedUserDataSources,
            });
```

But this does not work. Can anybody tell me how to solve it?

Comment: How does `schedulerUsersSource` looks like? What does `this does not work` (exactly) mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can't use more than one DataSource in Kendo UI components.**

About your code, you should remove the comma (",") at the end

```
value: selectedUserDataSources
```

if you want to be sure that it works, try to not setting the initial value (value field)

```
 $("#shareReadMultiSelect").kendoMultiSelect(
 {
     autoBind: true,
     dataSource: schedulerUsersSource,
     dataTextField: "text",
     dataValueField: "value"
 });
```